# Diagnosing buzzing / grinding sound

Tags: noise, acura, integra

95 Acura integer makes a plastic buzzing sound for 15-60 seconds after startup.  Sound eventually stops.  Sound is originating from white box:

[image]

The goal is to understand the cause of the sound and corrective action.  What are the steps to diagnose root cause of the sound?  Any lessons-learned or relevant experience is always appreciated.

Comment: The white box you're looking at is the ABS module. The noise will probably be related to the ABS warning light you asked about in [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/80037)

Answer (score 1):

This is the brake fluid tank. Underneath it likely has the ABS actuators, which likely make the sound you are hearing. I'd start by diagnosing ABS (with a scanner). If you don't have the scanner that can diagnose ABS - pull the ABS fuse and start the car to see if the sound is still there.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Are you able to provide a link to a ABS scanner?  I ask because I am trying to understand if it is ODB tip scanner or a scanner specifically used only for ABS.  Unfortunately the '95 misses the cut for the ODB2 compliance mandate

Comment: @gatorback, yes, unfortunately '95 Integra does not appear to have OBDII. Here's a link to an forum post explaining how to pull codes on Acura without OBDII. https://www.team-integra.net/threads/abs-codes-94-97.173389/